# Traffic from mobile apps doesn't reflect in my Burp Suite

Tags: applications, linux, windows, proxy

I need to send the traffic from mobile apps to my proxy (Burp). When I finally did it, I found out that everything is working only in Windows.
The traffic from mobile apps is reflected in a Burp only in a Windows OS.

When I try to do the same things (set Burp on my IP and `adb shell settings put global http_proxy ip:port`) in Kali, it doesn't work at all.

What can be wrong? Of course, I could work in Windows, but Kali is my main OS with a settled environment. So I need your advice.

Comment: Do you boot your system using kali or does it run in a VM? If you boot it as main OS on the PC make sure the Burp port is not blocked by the firewall of Kali.

Comment: Hello! yes I boot kali as main OS. 
How I can check that burp port isn't blocked by fw?

Comment: Robert I disable my FW - the status is inactive. So there is no problem in FW.

Comment: If Burp can correctly get the traffic when running on Windows but not on Kali, then it is an problem of the OS. So it is Independent of Android and this site is dedicated to Android questions. You may get more feed back when asking on a site more specific to Kali or Linux in general.

Comment: Tnaks bud! I'll try to ask somewhere else.